# self-adjoint bounded generates analytic semigroup

Tags: functional-analysis, semigroup-of-operators

[Engel Nagel A Short Course on Operator Semigroups](https://www.springer.com/book/9780387313412) Corollary II.4.8 states:
[image]
(There should be a typo. If $\delta=0$ then the spectum is empty, but normal operator has a non-empty spectrum? Anyways,)

Then they proceed,

> In particular, Corollary 4.8 shows that the semigroup generated by a self-adjoint operator A that is bounded above, which means that there exists $w\in\mathbb{R}$ such that
>   $$
> ( A x | x ) \leq w \| x \| ^ { 2 } \quad \text { for all } x \in D ( A )
> $$
>   is analytic of angle $\pi/2$. Moreover, this semigroup is bounded if and only if
>   $w\leq 0$.

I do not see how Corollary 4.8 implies this. If $w=0$, then $(Ax|x)\leq 0$, so it is still possible that $0\in \sigma(A)$. But $0\not\in \{z\in\mathbb{C}\mid |\arg(-z)|<\delta\}$.

Are we meant to consider something like $A+w$, consider ${e}^{t(A+w)}$ and then say ${e}^{tA}$ is well-defined further ${e}^{t(A+w)}={e}^{tA}e^{tw}$ etc.?

Comment: There is a typo (or, more precisely, $\mathrm{arg}(0)$ is not well-defined). It should be $\sigma(A)\subseteq \{z\in\mathbb{C}: |\mathrm{arg}(-z)|<\delta\}\cup \{0\}$.

Comment: Ah, I thought it should be $|\arg(-z)|\leq \delta$ so that for $\delta=0$ we have self-adjoint negative definite. Your corrected assumption makes the result stronger than my version, which I guess is related to an answer of yours (Pazy's $0\in \rho(A)$ is not needed). Thanks!

Comment: You have to clarify whether $0\in \sigma(A)$ is allowed or not. For every $z\neq 0$ it does not matter if there is $<$ or $\leq$, you can always replace $\delta$ by $\delta'\in (\delta,\pi/2)$.

Comment: I was looking at Yagi before this and thought  $\sigma(A)\subseteq {|\arg(−z)|\leq \delta}$ implicitly excludes $0$. But now I see $0\in\sigma(A)$ is fine. Thanks for the discussion on this typo.